# How to get all memory address space used by a process?

Tags: c#, memory, interop, intptr

I need to know all memory address space used by a process. The memory space will later be scanned to locate values within the process and identify their locations / addresses. My current process for this is to take each module's base address through its (base address + memory size).

I'm testing this on a process with a known value at a known address. When I look up that specific address, I get the value I expect. However, when I scan (what I believe to be) all address space used by the process, I can't find the value anywhere.

I know that a numeric value "4143000" exists at *0x0CF8DC38* and *0x0CF8DDDC*. When I call *ReadMemoryBytes(module, module.BaseAddress, 4, (IntPtr)(0x0CF8DC38))* I get back bytes (152, 55, 63, 0). When I call BitConverter.GetBytes(4143000) I get back the same set of bytes. When I use a different memory scanner on that process, I find that value at those addresses.

However, when I scan the "known addresses", I don't find this value anywhere. It doesn't look like my code is even finding those addresses in use by the process.

Thusly, my question is twofold:

- How can I find these addresses within this process?
- I'm concerned I may be dealing with absolute addresses in system memory versus relative addresses within a process. Am I doing this right?

.

```
// (in the calling method)
foreach (ProcessModule module in process.Modules) {
    ParameterizedThreadStart pst = new ParameterizedThreadStart(p => SearchModule(module, value));
    Thread t = new Thread(pst);
    t.Start(); }

private unsafe void SearchModule(ProcessModule module, string value)
{
Process process = getProcess;
int iVal;
double dVal;
int.TryParse(value, out iVal);
double.TryParse(value, out dVal);
for (Int64 addr = (Int64)module.BaseAddress; addr + value.Length < (Int64)module.BaseAddress + module.ModuleMemorySize; addr++)
{
    // Compare ints
    if (iVal > 0)
    {
        byte[] ExpectedBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(iVal);
        byte[] ActualBytes = ReadMemoryBytes(module, (IntPtr)addr, (uint)ExpectedBytes.Length, (IntPtr)addr);

        bool isMatch = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < ExpectedBytes.Length; i++)
            if (ExpectedBytes[i] != ActualBytes[i])
                isMatch = false;
        if (isMatch)
            PossibleAddresses.Add((IntPtr)addr);
    }
}

private byte[] ReadMemoryBytes(ProcessModule mod, IntPtr memAddress, uint size, IntPtr BaseAddress)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    IntPtr bytesRead;
    unsafe
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(processPointer, BaseAddress, buffer, size, out bytesRead);
        return buffer;
    }
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(UInt32 dwDesiredAccess, Int32 bInheritHandle, UInt32 dwProcessId);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [In, Out] byte[] buffer, UInt32 size, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);
```

Comment: Your faulty assumption is that (from MSDN): "ModuleMemorySize does not include any additional memory allocations that the module makes once it is running; it includes only the size of the static code and data in the module file."  So your loop doesn't look everywhere.  What you need is an overall memory map of the process, but I'm not sure how you can do that in C#.  The sysinternals VMMap tool can do it, but there's no source for it available... (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addresses you're getting are pointers to the managed (CLR) heap. They won't generally map to absolute memory addresses and they can move from call to call as the GC decides to run.

If you use "unsafe" code, you can get relative pointers as well as managing your own memory space. It's still on the heap but at least you're guaranteed the GC won't modify your address space.

Do not expect to be able to access things on the heap from non-CLR code without extensive wrapping. There are ways to do IPC between CLR-managed processes but you'd have to write access proxies to the "outside world" if you want a non-CLR process to get to your memory.