# Memory Scanner not finding results

Tags: c#, pointers, memory, readprocessmemory

Im writing a small memory scanner application to find pointers in the memory.
But i don't seem to be getting the expected results.

I have the following code:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [Out] byte[] buffer, UInt32 size, IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

public int ReadInt(long Address)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
    ReadProcessMemory(ProcessHandle, (IntPtr)Address, buffer, 4, IntPtr.Zero); // this always returns true
    return BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
}

public List<long> SearchInt(long start, long end, int value)
{
    List<long> results = new List<long>();
    for (long i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ReadInt(i) == value)
                results.Add(i);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            break; // no exceptions occur
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

if i call the method like this:

```
SearchInt(baseAddress.ToInt64(), lastAddress.ToInt64(), 1234)
```

I know for a fact that the process im reading has an integer with the value of 1234 but i don't get any results. If i scan for other values i sometimes get results.

`baseAddress` is `process.MainModule.BaseAddress`
and
`lastAddress` is `baseAddress + process.MainModule.ModuleMemorySize`

Am i missing somthing here?

Comment: You are hiding exceptions. At least log them using Debug.WriteLine() so you can see if the loop is exiting early due to an exception.

Comment: there is no exceptions.

Comment: On a 64-bit processor, `i++` will 'jump' 8 bytes.

Comment: what should i do instead?

Comment: No it won't it will increment i by one, which is then used as an address up by one byte.

Comment: This is a 64-bit OS and app but it seems `i++` and `i = i + 1` both increment by 1, therefore increasing the pointer value by 1. This is what i thought would happen.

Comment: I created another app that has a global integer with the value `1234` and it never found it but it finds a few results for `1` and `0` and some others.

Comment: @NicolasTyler Finding `0` is no big feat. Any empty memory block can be read as an `int` with 0 value. How are you defining the ints? `const`?

Comment: This is true and i know. I over get 27000 results for `0` and only 15 for `1`. And no im just making it public. But this should not make a difference the variable should be stored in the memory.

Comment: The `buffer` parameter to `ReadProcessMemory` should be `[Out]`, rather than `[In, Out]`, but I don't see where the way you have it would cause it to read wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This would not work if the value you are searching for is initialized at runtime and not a part of the static compiled code. It would then lie outside the memory area defined by `BaseAddress` + `ModuleMemorySize`

From [`ProcessModule.ModuleMemorySize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processmodule.modulememorysize.aspx):

> ModuleMemorySize does not include any additional memory allocations
>   that the module makes once it is running; it includes only the size of
>   the static code and data in the module file.

Comment: Ok im going to scan the entire memory and see if i get results.

Comment: @NicolasTyler If the value you are searching for is a class member, it may be stored on the heap, see a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242537/how-to-get-all-memory-address-space-used-by-a-process

Comment: It seems that any address other than the addresses between baseAddress  and lastAddress all have the value of zero. So its pointless scanning other addresses.